# Django not see the table in generic relation

Tags: python, django, database, backend, django-generic-relations

I'm working with Django 1.7.2 with generic relation (reason: project has two databases), and after import I don't want to have overwritten database.

I want to show only active season

Here is my model, is overwritten after import:

```
class Season(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=255)
    start = models.DateField('Start')
    end = models.DateField('End')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

In another place in models.py file I create Generic relation to another model (SaleAndCycle) in another database:

```
def extend_models(sender, **kwargs):
    if sender._meta.app_label != 'extend':
        return
    def set_stati(self, database='extend', save=True):
        online_before = self.online
        self.online = True
        for flag in self.flags:
            if flag.flag == 'offline':
                self.online = False
        if save and self.online != online_before:
            self.save(using=database)

    for name, name_singular, name_plural in (
        ('Season', 'Season', 'Seasons'):
        if sender.__name__ == name:
            sender._meta.verbose_name = name_singular
            sender._meta.verbose_name_plural = name_plural
    if sender.__name__ == 'Season':
        sender.add_to_class('sale_and_cycles', generic.GenericRelation(SaleAndCycle))
        sender.add_to_class('is_sale_active', property(
            lambda o: o.sale_and_cycles.using('default')))
        sender.add_to_class('is_cyclic_event_active', property(
            lambda o: o.sale_and_cycles.using('default')))
        sender.add_to_class('cycle_link', property(
            lambda o: o.sale_and_cycles.using('default')))
```

I want to show all active Seasons for not login user:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    seasons = Season.objects.all()
    if not self.request.user.is_superuser:
        all_seasons = Season.objects.filter(events_isactiveflags__is_active=True)
        print all_seasons
```

I get error:

```
no such table: events_isactiveflag
```

But this table exists in my database.

Comment: Django 1.7.2??? Seriously? Why not trying to update to a more recent version, instead?

Comment: @nik_m because this is old project

Comment: Can you edit the question by adding the code where the events_isactiveflag table is created. This will help to quickly debug the same.

Comment: @AbijithMg done, please check.

Answer (score 1):

by the line of code

```
Season.objects.filter(events_isactiveflags__is_active=True)
```

here   `events_isactiveflags__is_active=True` means **events_isactiveflags** is a table and **is_active** is a column of the table. So no such table found named **events_isactiveflags** . if you are trying to get active sessions you can try this code

```
Session.objects.filter(expire_date__gte=timezone.now())
```

Comment: This is not solution because user have to set which season is active, it should be boolean field.

Comment: you can check by using Season.objects.filter(is_active=True)

Answer (score 0):

delete db and once again run syncdb